# Working of the Peak Torque in a BLDC

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect, circuits

We have a BLDC motor of the following specifications , and I wanted to ask that :- If the Peak Torque lasts for about 10 seconds once activated, then after what time interval can it be activated again?
[image: BLDC SPECIFICATIONS]

Comment: The motor is thermally limited. You need to ensure the motor temperature doesn’t exceed a given value. The duty cycle depends on the environmental coditions that affect how quickly the motor cools.

Comment: The question can only be answered by the motor manufacturer. Unfortunately the specification does not provide complete information. The momentary torque specification is practically worthless without the minimum rest time. Voting to close the question.

Comment: After long enough to cool down. If the motor is fully specified, that will be in the datasheet somewhere (maybe in the form of a "duty cycle" rating). If it is not, you'll have to characterise it yourself, perhaps by comparing to rated torque. For example you might use the fact that Peak Torque = 300% of rated torque and thus Peak I = 300% of rated I, dissipating 900% nominal power in the winding, to assume a 1/9 duty cycle might work, and test that typothesis. This maintains the same mean resistive losses in the motor as rated torque.

Comment: Only guessing: it should be something like 300% for 10s and then 3 minutes if the torque doesn't exceed 80% nominal. Or, if the motor is running at 100% torque, then there no  possibility for a 10s boost. It all about winding temperature, the approximation is a I^2*t integral, while the best is the temp. sensor.